# How to find the $k$ value in this question?

Tags: vector-spaces

Calculate $k$ such that $u=(1,1,1)$, $v=(k,0,1)$ and $w=(2,-1,-2)$ are linearly dependent, but are pairwise linearly independent.

Comment: what is $K$ suppose to be?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: We see that $u + w = (3,0,-1)$.  For what $k$ is $v$ spanned by $u + w$?